# Architecture for streaming an endless video queue with mysql datasource

Tags: php, web-services, video, streaming, video-streaming

right now i'm building a webinterface. It should be something like a media control system. In this interface a user can select some vid's from a coverflow'ish style and put the videos in a queue. The queue is visualized like a timeline. This interface is webbased, made with TYPO3 FLOW. So i got in my database data to play/stream.

I'm trying to figure out how to stream my selected data. I'd prefer a webbased solution but i'm open for everything.

Could anyone please give me a hint what kind of technique would fit best? This is what i need:

- the playlist/queue is stored in a database (not the videos itself but the meta-data and file-urls)
- people can add items to the queue over a webinterface (already implemented)
- if the queue / playlist is empty i'd like to play some random videos
- if someone adds a video to the playlist / queue this video needs to be played at a given time (mostly now()+60sec if the queue is empty, endtime last clip +x when not)
- if i open the stream while a video is started in the queue the video should start at that time should be at

So i need to stream dynamicly videos with in an endless loop. I'd love to have a webbased solution. Like something with node.js and vidStreamer.js but i'm not familiar with it yet. Would it be possible to play content dynamically, based on mysql input?

Answer (score 0):

I would do that mostly client side with Javascript. Export the metadata and preload the videos hidden from view, then start as needed. With HTML5 video you have easily access to the video and player properties so you can get the timing right.